# updating a 2d array in mongoose when position is known to us

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this seats property on my schema now what i want is to update a particular position in the array suppose 2nd row 3rd column i want to change the value from 0 to 1 how do i query such a thing

```
const seatsSchema=new Schema({seats : {
        type:Mixed,
        default:[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
    }
})
```

Thanks